# Snowflake: SQL compilation error: error line invalid identifier '"dateutc"'

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm moving data from Postgres to snowflake. Originally it worked however I've added:

```
df_postgres["dateutc"]= pd.to_datetime(df_postgres["dateutc"])
```

because the date format was incorrectly loading to snowflake and now I see this error:

> SQL compilation error: error line 1 at position 87 invalid identifier
> '"dateutc"'

Here is my code:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
from config import postgres_user, postgres_pass, host,port, postgres_db, snow_user, snow_pass,snow_account,snow_warehouse   
from snowflake.connector.pandas_tools import pd_writer
from snowflake.sqlalchemy import URL


from sqlalchemy.dialects import registry
registry.register('snowflake', 'snowflake.sqlalchemy', 'dialect')

    
engine = create_engine(f'postgresql://{postgres_user}:{postgres_pass}@{host}:{port}/{postgres_db}')


conn = engine.connect()

#reads query
df_postgres = pd.read_sql("SELECT * FROM rok.my_table", conn)

#dropping these columns
drop_cols=['RPM', 'RPT']
df_postgres.drop(drop_cols, inplace=True, axis=1)

#changed columns to lowercase
df_postgres.columns = df_postgres.columns.str.lower()


df_postgres["dateutc"]= pd.to_datetime(df_postgres["dateutc"])


print(df_postgres.dateutc.dtype)

sf_conn = create_engine(URL(
    account = snow_account,
    user = snow_user,
    password = snow_pass,
    database = 'test',
    schema = 'my_schema',
    warehouse = 'test',
    role = 'test',
))



df_postgres.to_sql(name='my_table',
                 index = False,  
                 con = sf_conn,
                 if_exists = 'append', 
                 chunksize = 300,
                 method = pd_writer)
```

Comment: I am somewhat certain that your table has at some point been created using *regular identifiers*, i.e. unquoted. Snowflake stores them in that case in uppercase: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/identifiers-syntax.html#label-identifier-casing. Now for some reason `pd_writer` is instructed to quote identifiers (*delimited*), and so `"dateutc"` cannot be found. That or the table really does not have the column, and since you use `'append'` it fails. Try naming it `DATEUTC` and see what happens.

Comment: @IljaEverilä thanks for responding, I saw you mentioned pd_writer, I removed that and it worked!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Moving Ilja's answer from comment to answer for completeness:

- Snowflake is case sensitive.
- When writing "unquoted" SQL, Snowflake will convert table names and fields to uppercase.
- This usually works, until someone decides to start quoting their identifiers in SQL.
- `pd_writer` adds quotes to identifiers.
- Hence when you have `df_postgres["dateutc"]` it remains in lowercase when its transformed into a fully quoted query.
- Writing `df_postgres["DATEUTC"]` in Python should fix the issue.

Comment: Could it btw. be that Pandas is actually creating the table first using regular identifiers because column names were all lower case, and then `pd_writer` does what it is supposed to, i.e. uses delimited identifiers? I see that similar issues have popped up [elsewhere](https://github.com/snowflakedb/snowflake-connector-python/issues/329) as [well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63370701/snowflake-pandas-pd-writer-writes-out-tables-with-nulls).

Comment: Confirming. Has the same error with `write_pandas`. I suggest converting all columns to upper case before using inserting. `df.columns = df.columns.str.upper()`